# CSS skewed sub-menu items displaying incorrectly

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm making an website with DIVI, and used custom CSS code to skew and style the menu buttons, but now i have this strange effect on drop-down submenus when they are out of the style completely.
I was trying to apply same styles for drop-down items, but nothing seems to work.
Maybe anyone ran in this problem? You can check the website live - http://steel.cody.lt and the problem is with PRODUCT menu dropdown.

Comment: Please go read [ask], [mcve] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this css and try

```
#top-menu-nav #top-menu li li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0px;
    line-height: 2em!important;
    width: 100%;
    transform: skew(-1deg);
}

#top-menu-nav #top-menu li li a {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 6px 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
```